# How to reduce Misclassification in images in CNN?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision, conv-neural-network

I am trying to classify between forged and real signatures using CNN. But, the model is always predicting forged even if the image is genuine also it is correctly predicting forged for real forged signature. Can body help me where i am getting wrong ? I have tried tuning hyperparameters but sometimes the model is biased towards genuine and sometimes it's forged. It's not giving correct prediction.

```
import os 
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense,Conv2D,Flatten,MaxPool2D,BatchNormalization,ZeroPadding2D
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping,ModelCheckpoint

train_path='/gdrive/MyDrive/dataset'
test_path='/gdrive/MyDrive/sample_Signature'

train=ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1/255,
    width_shift_range=0.2,
    height_shift_range=0.2,
    rotation_range=20,
    horizontal_flip=True
)
test=ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1/255
)

size=128
train_image_gen=train.flow_from_directory(train_path,batch_size=5,color_mode='rgb',class_mode='binary',target_size=(size,size))
test_image_gen=test.flow_from_directory(test_path,batch_size=5,color_mode='rgb',class_mode='binary',target_size=(size,size))

Found 1712 images belonging to 2 classes.
Found 300 images belonging to 2 classes.



test_image_gen.class_indices
{'forged': 0, 'genuine': 1}
model=Sequential([
                  Conv2D(96,kernel_size=(3,3),strides=4,activation='relu',input_shape=(size,size,3)),
                  MaxPool2D((2,2)),
                  BatchNormalization(),
                  ZeroPadding2D((2,2)),
                  Conv2D(256,kernel_size=(5,5),activation='relu'),
                  MaxPool2D((2,2)),
                  Conv2D(384,kernel_size=(3,3),activation='relu'),
                  MaxPool2D((2,2)),
                  BatchNormalization(),
                  ZeroPadding2D((1,1)),
                  Flatten(),
                  Dense(1024,activation='relu'),
                  Dense(128,activation='relu'),
                  Dense(1,activation='sigmoid')

])
# model=Sequential([
#                   Conv2D(90,kernel_size=(3,3),activation='relu',input_shape=(size,size,3)),
#                   MaxPool2D((2,2)),
#                   Flatten(),
#                   Dense(128,activation='relu'),
#                   Dense(1,activation='sigmoid')
# ])
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',optimizer='adam',metrics=['accuracy'])

filepath="weights-improvement-{epoch:02d}-{val_accuracy:.2f}.h5"
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(filepath, monitor='val_accuracy', verbose=1, save_best_only=True, mode='max')
callbacks_list = [checkpoint]

model.fit(train_image_gen,validation_data=test_image_gen,callbacks=callbacks_list,epochs=40,validation_steps=12)
Epoch 1/40
343/343 [==============================] - 21s 60ms/step - loss: 0.6388 - accuracy: 0.6361 - val_loss: 1.0792 - val_accuracy: 0.5167

Epoch 00001: val_accuracy did not improve from 0.58667
Epoch 2/40
343/343 [==============================] - 20s 60ms/step - loss: 0.6272 - accuracy: 0.6303 - val_loss: 1.5772 - val_accuracy: 0.5000

Epoch 00002: val_accuracy did not improve from 0.58667
Epoch 3/40
343/343 [==============================] - 21s 61ms/step - loss: 0.6181 - accuracy: 0.6507 - val_loss: 1.4445 - val_accuracy: 0.5500

Epoch 00003: val_accuracy did not improve from 0.58667
Epoch 4/40
343/343 [==============================] - 21s 61ms/step - loss: 0.6269 - accuracy: 0.6355 - val_loss: 3.4749 - val_accuracy: 0.5667

Epoch 00004: val_accuracy did not improve from 0.58667
Epoch 5/40
343/343 [==============================] - 21s 61ms/step - loss: 0.6261 - accuracy: 0.6379 - val_loss: 1.9042 - val_accuracy: 0.4667

Epoch 00005: val_accuracy did not improve from 0.58667
Epoch 6/40
343/343 [==============================] - 20s 58ms/step - loss: 0.6123 - accuracy: 0.6671 - val_loss: 0.6712 - val_accuracy: 0.5833

Epoch 00006: val_accuracy did not improve from 0.58667
Epoch 7/40
343/343 [==============================] - 20s 59ms/step - loss: 0.6221 - accuracy: 0.6478 - val_loss: 0.8703 - val_accuracy: 0.5167

Epoch 00007: val_accuracy did not improve from 0.58667
Epoch 8/40
343/343 [==============================] - 20s 60ms/step - loss: 0.6089 - accuracy: 0.6600 - val_loss: 0.7600 - val_accuracy: 0.4500

Epoch 00008: val_accuracy did not improve from 0.58667
Epoch 9/40
343/343 [==============================] - 21s 60ms/step - loss: 0.6048 - accuracy: 0.6565 - val_loss: 1.9563 - val_accuracy: 0.5667

Epoch 00009: val_accuracy did not improve from 0.58667
Epoch 10/40
343/343 [==============================] - 21s 61ms/step - loss: 0.6066 - accuracy: 0.6589 - val_loss: 2.1305 - val_accuracy: 0.5333

Epoch 00010: val_accuracy did not improve from 0.58667
Epoch 11/40
343/343 [==============================] - 21s 60ms/step - loss: 0.6182 - accuracy: 0.6659 - val_loss: 1.2003 - val_accuracy: 0.5500

Epoch 00011: val_accuracy did not improve from 0.58667
Epoch 12/40
343/343 [==============================] - 21s 60ms/step - loss: 0.6110 - accuracy: 0.6606 - val_loss: 0.6984 - val_accuracy: 0.4833

Epoch 00012: val_accuracy did not improve from 0.58667
Epoch 13/40
343/343 [==============================] - 21s 61ms/step - loss: 0.6030 - accuracy: 0.6653 - val_loss: 1.3894 - val_accuracy: 0.6167

Epoch 00013: val_accuracy improved from 0.58667 to 0.61667, saving model to weights-improvement-13-0.62.h5
Epoch 14/40
343/343 [==============================] - 21s 62ms/step - loss: 0.5934 - accuracy: 0.6846 - val_loss: 1.9208 - val_accuracy: 0.4667

Epoch 00014: val_accuracy did not improve from 0.61667
Epoch 15/40
343/343 [==============================] - 21s 62ms/step - loss: 0.5905 - accuracy: 0.6688 - val_loss: 1.9536 - val_accuracy: 0.5667

Epoch 00015: val_accuracy did not improve from 0.61667
Epoch 16/40
343/343 [==============================] - 22s 64ms/step - loss: 0.6037 - accuracy: 0.6565 - val_loss: 4.5003 - val_accuracy: 0.4500

Epoch 00016: val_accuracy did not improve from 0.61667
Epoch 17/40
343/343 [==============================] - 22s 64ms/step - loss: 0.5993 - accuracy: 0.6764 - val_loss: 2.2383 - val_accuracy: 0.4000

Epoch 00017: val_accuracy did not improve from 0.61667
Epoch 18/40
343/343 [==============================] - 22s 63ms/step - loss: 0.5894 - accuracy: 0.6729 - val_loss: 1.8708 - val_accuracy: 0.5667

Epoch 00018: val_accuracy did not improve from 0.61667
Epoch 19/40
343/343 [==============================] - 20s 59ms/step - loss: 0.5935 - accuracy: 0.6676 - val_loss: 0.7177 - val_accuracy: 0.6000

Epoch 00019: val_accuracy did not improve from 0.61667
Epoch 20/40
343/343 [==============================] - 21s 61ms/step - loss: 0.5818 - accuracy: 0.6928 - val_loss: 3.2934 - val_accuracy: 0.5167

Epoch 00020: val_accuracy did not improve from 0.61667
Epoch 21/40
343/343 [==============================] - 21s 62ms/step - loss: 0.5861 - accuracy: 0.6817 - val_loss: 64.1771 - val_accuracy: 0.4500

Epoch 00021: val_accuracy did not improve from 0.61667
Epoch 22/40
343/343 [==============================] - 21s 62ms/step - loss: 0.5805 - accuracy: 0.6904 - val_loss: 1.6736 - val_accuracy: 0.5833

Epoch 00022: val_accuracy did not improve from 0.61667
Epoch 23/40
343/343 [==============================] - 21s 61ms/step - loss: 0.5739 - accuracy: 0.7015 - val_loss: 71.6395 - val_accuracy: 0.5500

Epoch 00023: val_accuracy did not improve from 0.61667
Epoch 24/40
343/343 [==============================] - 22s 63ms/step - loss: 0.5632 - accuracy: 0.7068 - val_loss: 171.9396 - val_accuracy: 0.4500

Epoch 00024: val_accuracy did not improve from 0.61667
Epoch 25/40
343/343 [==============================] - 22s 64ms/step - loss: 0.5731 - accuracy: 0.6986 - val_loss: 58.0860 - val_accuracy: 0.5000

Epoch 00025: val_accuracy did not improve from 0.61667
Epoch 26/40
343/343 [==============================] - 23s 66ms/step - loss: 0.5620 - accuracy: 0.6945 - val_loss: 1.1772 - val_accuracy: 0.5167

Epoch 00026: val_accuracy did not improve from 0.61667
Epoch 27/40
343/343 [==============================] - 21s 61ms/step - loss: 0.5766 - accuracy: 0.6916 - val_loss: 1.2711 - val_accuracy: 0.6167

Epoch 00027: val_accuracy did not improve from 0.61667
Epoch 28/40
343/343 [==============================] - 21s 61ms/step - loss: 0.5763 - accuracy: 0.6863 - val_loss: 1.5297 - val_accuracy: 0.4500

Epoch 00028: val_accuracy did not improve from 0.61667
Epoch 29/40
343/343 [==============================] - 21s 61ms/step - loss: 0.5561 - accuracy: 0.7161 - val_loss: 1.1575 - val_accuracy: 0.5833

Epoch 00029: val_accuracy did not improve from 0.61667
Epoch 30/40
343/343 [==============================] - 21s 61ms/step - loss: 0.5544 - accuracy: 0.7103 - val_loss: 1060.0918 - val_accuracy: 0.5167

Epoch 00030: val_accuracy did not improve from 0.61667
Epoch 31/40
343/343 [==============================] - 21s 61ms/step - loss: 0.5713 - accuracy: 0.7009 - val_loss: 5.6437 - val_accuracy: 0.5667

Epoch 00031: val_accuracy did not improve from 0.61667
Epoch 32/40
343/343 [==============================] - 21s 60ms/step - loss: 0.5605 - accuracy: 0.7039 - val_loss: 1.7087 - val_accuracy: 0.5333

Epoch 00032: val_accuracy did not improve from 0.61667
Epoch 33/40
343/343 [==============================] - 21s 63ms/step - loss: 0.5548 - accuracy: 0.7138 - val_loss: 2.7001 - val_accuracy: 0.5333

Epoch 00033: val_accuracy did not improve from 0.61667
Epoch 34/40
343/343 [==============================] - 21s 61ms/step - loss: 0.5520 - accuracy: 0.7196 - val_loss: 1.5627 - val_accuracy: 0.4667

Epoch 00034: val_accuracy did not improve from 0.61667
Epoch 35/40
343/343 [==============================] - 21s 62ms/step - loss: 0.5424 - accuracy: 0.7383 - val_loss: 1.1802 - val_accuracy: 0.6167

Epoch 00035: val_accuracy did not improve from 0.61667
Epoch 36/40
343/343 [==============================] - 21s 62ms/step - loss: 0.5387 - accuracy: 0.7319 - val_loss: 1.8260 - val_accuracy: 0.6167

Epoch 00036: val_accuracy did not improve from 0.61667
Epoch 37/40
343/343 [==============================] - 21s 62ms/step - loss: 0.5270 - accuracy: 0.7424 - val_loss: 1.1755 - val_accuracy: 0.5167

Epoch 00037: val_accuracy did not improve from 0.61667
Epoch 38/40
343/343 [==============================] - 22s 64ms/step - loss: 0.5301 - accuracy: 0.7313 - val_loss: 0.8804 - val_accuracy: 0.5667

Epoch 00038: val_accuracy did not improve from 0.61667
Epoch 39/40
343/343 [==============================] - 20s 59ms/step - loss: 0.5231 - accuracy: 0.7465 - val_loss: 0.9558 - val_accuracy: 0.7167

Epoch 00039: val_accuracy improved from 0.61667 to 0.71667, saving model to weights-improvement-39-0.72.h5
Epoch 40/40
343/343 [==============================] - 22s 65ms/step - loss: 0.5030 - accuracy: 0.7453 - val_loss: 2.3641 - val_accuracy: 0.6000
```

testing the genuine images

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model

model=load_model('weights-improvement-39-0.72.h5')

data='/gdrive/MyDrive/rb2/genuine'
for i in os.listdir(data):
  new=data+'/'+i
  imag=image.load_img(new,target_size=(size,size))
  ima=image.img_to_array(imag).reshape(1,size,size,3)
  if model.predict(ima)==1:
    print('Genuine')
  else:
    print('forged')
forged
forged
forged
forged
forged
```

Comment: With a first look, I will say you need more data. Moreover, you are overfitting. I would recommend you use a pretrained model. Also plot the confusion matrix, maybe your model is always predicting only one unique class.

Comment: How to get pertained model ?

Comment: You have to use an existing model. [Here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/transfer_learning_with_hub) you have an example. Using this model you will obtain a better accuracy for sure.

Comment: You are not making predictions correctly, it is not correct to compare the output of predict with a value of 1.0, you should put a threshold at 0.5 (model.predict() > 0.5).

Comment: I did that too..but result is still the same.